# VBA Excel: Apply height and width sizes to more than one graph

Tags: vba, excel, graph, charts

I have an Excel spread sheet that has multiple graphs on one sheet, these graphs are hidden or displayed based on user selection. What I want to do is safeguard the graphs from user error by programmatically adjusting their height and width when the sheet changes. I have code in the Worksheet Change so that the graphs are hidden/displayed and wish to insert the height and width code here, the problem I have though is that I have found code to adjust the height and width of one graph:

```
    With ChartObjects("Test")
        .height = 300
        .width = 500
    End With
```

But applying this to many graphs would be ugly, and the code I found to adjust all the graphs:

```
 Dim cht As ChartObject

 For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

    cht.Height = Application.InchesToPoints(2)

    cht.Width = Application.InchesToPoints(4)

 Next
```

Would mean that all the charts have the same size whereas I have 2 different sizes for the charts (small and large), which can be differentiated by the chart name as the small charts include "small" in the chart name and large charts have "large" in the chart name.

So is it possible to run code that will change the size of charts based on whether the chart contains the word "small" or "large" in its name?

Please note that I am using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not test the name in your loop using `instr` and an `if` statement. Just update this with the correct sizes

```
Dim cht As ChartObject

 For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    With cht
        If InStr(1, .Name, "small", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            .Height = Application.InchesToPoints(2)
            .Width = Application.InchesToPoints(4)
        ElseIf InStr(1, .Name, "large", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            .Height = Application.InchesToPoints(4)
            .Width = Application.InchesToPoints(8)
        End If
    End With
 Next cht
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!